# How to extract markers for Watershed via image processing methods?

Tags: algorithm, opencv, image-processing, watershed

I'm writing application with OpenCV that should segmentate an image like attached below, using watershed segmentation with markers, without the user manually marking the image. 
I've tried to use threshhold and distance transformation for it, but results not so good. Could you please give me piece of advice how can I extract markers for this task?

[image: Image Example]

Comment: its better you use a neural network to make segmentation

Comment: I know about neural network methods, but want to use classic algorithm too

Comment: I would recommend something similar to this (https://github.com/higra/Higra-Notebooks/blob/master/Watershed%20hierarchies.ipynb), I think it is the best you can get without using user interaction or deep learning.